# qTip2. I'm not able to add the "position" code

Tags: javascript, syntax, qtip2

I don't know nothing about javascript. Could someone explain me what is wrong in this code (it's a syntax error)?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('.picture').qtip(
{
    content: {
             text: $(this).next('.tooltiptext')
             }
    position: {
            my: 'bottom center',  // tooltips tip at bottom center...
            at: 'top center', // in relation to the button's top center...
            target: $('.picture') // my target
              }
 });
});
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: If it was an syntax error, there would be a console error - Press `F12` to see

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing a `,` between the properties values of your qtip.

Try:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.picture').qtip({
        content: {
            text: $(this).next('.tooltiptext')
        }, // <-- here
        position: {
            my: 'bottom center', // tooltips tip at bottom center...
            at: 'top center', // in relation to the button's top center...
            target: $('.picture') // my target
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much Irvin! The qTip is now at the right position but he didn't show the content of the .tooltiptext div. Any clue?

Comment: (I'm sorry, as new user I don't have the permission to poste a new answer until tomorrow). My HtML is OK. It means that qTip works perfectly if I remove the "position". The .tooltiptex div is a regular HTML div. I think that something in the javascript still missing... Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Have you got multiple elements with class __picture__, please edit the question and provide your HTML markup